# Margin-top shows up as .5% even though it's coded at 0%, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div with a width of 98%, and a left and right margin of 1%. I'm also trying to get a top margin of 0%, but for some reason the top margin shows up as .5%, even though I specifically put 0%. I don't know what I did wrong, please take a look at my code:

```
#div {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 98%;
height: 98%;
margin-top: 0%;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
}

<div id = 'div'></div>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that code. On this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lqbkhdk/) it seems to work fine (computes as `0px` on the top margin). I suspect that your problem might come from whatever container the `div` is being placed in. Perhaps provide some context on where `#div` is placed in your document.

Comment: @Singular1ty In that jsFiddle, the whole div only shows up as a line, which is not suppose to happen. Also, I'm seeing a space up top in there too. The #div is not placed inside anything in the document. The above code contains all the code for that page.

Comment: What browser are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: @frosty Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lqbkhdk/1/) closer to what you were thinking of? It's forming a large box, essentially.

Comment: @Singular1ty Yes, that's exactly it. On second thought, I could've just use the body tag instead of the div tag if I wanted the margin-top to be 0, since by default the #div is being placed inside the body tag, and I guess that's why there was a .5% space on top.

Comment: 0 value doesn't need any unit, why specify percentage?

Comment: @LaurentS. Because by default the margin might be more than 0.

Comment: 0%, 0px, 0em are all the same, margin-top: 0; is the correct notation.

Comment: @LaurentS. Never really thought about zero not needing an unit, I guess. Since everything bigger than zero needs an unit, and usually I use numbers bigger than zero, and thus usually I always assign them an unit. But, nice catch, regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the white space at top is the default top margin on the `body` element, which you need to zero out manually.

Also, you need to assign a height of 100% to the body and html elements or else the `div`'s height will compute to zero.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id='div'></div>
```